# Finding documents with Lucene where a term occurs more than a certain number of times

Tags: search, solr, lucene

Is there a way to create using Solr (or Lucene directly) a query that will find documents that contain a term more than a certain number of times?

Currently I've only managed to come up with a roundabout solution using SpanNearQuery. This can be used to say two spans are near each other, so by using n - 1 inOrder SpanNearQuerys such a query could be constructed e.g. "term" must occur 4 times:
(("term" near "term") near "term") near "term"

where "term" is a SpanTermQuery and near is an inOrder SpanNearQuery with large slop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**termfreq** function query](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html) used to fetch the frequency of the term and and further, the [Function range query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-FunctionRangeQueryParser) can be used that allows range queries or range filters over arbitrary functions.

```
q=*&fq={!frange l=2}termfreq(category_t,'demo')
```

Above query is only fetching those documents in which demo is repeating two times or more in `category_t` field.